# Exclude urls from authentication spring security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I try to exclude some urls from security config to allow access without jwt token authentication but I don't understand why it's work for the get method (/v1/all see my code bellow) and not for the post method (/v1/user-subscription see my code bellow, it has always need authentication although I declare it permitAll).

Any idea ?

Here is my security config

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/v1/all", "GET"), new AntPathRequestMatcher("/v1/user-subscription", "POST"))
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
            .jwt();
    return http.build();
}
```

And controller here :

```
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE, makeFinal = true)
public class UserSubscription {

UserService userService;

    @PostMapping("/v1/user-subscription")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> createUser(User user) {
    userService.createUser(user);
    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
}
```

User service :

```
public void createUser(User user) {

    RoleEntity roleEntity = roleRepository.findByRoleById(user.getId());

    String userId = user.getId();

    userRepository.findByRole(roleEntity).ifPresentOrElse(userEntity -> {
        UserEntity userUpdated = userEntity.toBuilder()
                .userId(userId)
                .build();
        userRepository.save(userUpdated);
    }, () -> {
        UserEntity newUser = UserEntity.builder()
                .userId(userId)
                .role(roleEntity)
                .build();
        userRepository.save(newUser);
    });
}
```

**After UPDATE**

[image]

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: what version of spring-boot starter are you using ?

Comment: I use 3.1.0 version

Comment: [i wrote in our chat an reason](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255542/discussion-on-answer-by-andrei-lisa-exclude-urls-from-authentication-spring-secu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all i want to say that you are using some deprecated/removed methods here in the `filterChain` configuration .

Next one implementation is going to solve your problem:

```
@Configuration
  @EnableWebSecurity
  public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
      http.authorizeHttpRequests(request -> {
        request.requestMatchers("/v1/all").permitAll();
        request.requestMatchers("/v1/user-subscription").permitAll();
        request.requestMatchers("/error/**").permitAll(); // it solve the problem
        request.anyRequest().authenticated();
      });
      http.oauth2ResourceServer(rS -> rS.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));
      return http.build();
    }}
```

To have more details about it i really suggest you to look at [Migration Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/config.html)

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255542/discussion-on-answer-by-andrei-lisa-exclude-urls-from-authentication-spring-secu); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.